# How to take a value at a pointer and copy into another pointer

Tags: c, pointers

I've got a method signature:

```
void word_not(lc3_word_t *R, lc3_word_t *A)
```

I need to take the contents of *A and copy them into *R.

How do I do this?

I've tried assignment

*R = *A; but my compiler complains.

Any ideas?

Comment: How does the compiler "complain"? (what's the error message?)

Comment: gcc -g -Wall -std=c99 -c logic.c
logic.c: In function ‘word_not’:
logic.c:18: error: incompatible types in assignment
make: *** [logic.o] Error 1

Comment: Uh... They're the exact same type? And it's giving you that?

Comment: What's the definition of `lc3_word_t`? Is it declared `const`?

Comment: can you please post the inside of your function, and aswell the defienition on lc3_word_t ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
memcpy(R, A, sizeof(lc3_word_t));
```

[memcpy](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstring/memcpy/) copies a specific number of bytes from A to R.  This assumes that this makes sense for the structs of type lc3_word_t that R points to allocated space.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, like David said, memcpy should help.

But make sure that memory is allocated to R, else you will end up corrupting memory of some other variables. And if you are planning to allocate memory inside this function (I would prefer this way) then change the signature as follows

```
void word_not(lc3_word_t **pR, lc3_word_t *A)
{
     *pR = (lc3_word_t*)malloc(sizeof(lc3_word_t));
     if(*pR != 0)
     {
          memcpy(*pR, A, sizeof(lc3_word_t));
     }
}
```